# Recurrent error when using pyinstaller & cx_Freeze

Tags: python-3.x, cmd, pyinstaller, exe

I've seen through the web that .exe taken from python scripts may often run into errors because of some "hooks missing", which happens because pyinstaller wasn't able to track some modules while creating the .exe file. I'm currently using Python IDLE 3.61 and the scripts works fine without any error. The .exe actually runs but, for instance, it simply crushes when I try to plot a table giving the error:

> NoModuleFoundError: 'No module=plotly.validators.table found'.

Building the .exe also via cx_Freeze, I came up to the same sort of problem:

> Module plotly.validators.table has no Attribute CellsValidators

which confirmed me the problem is caused by issues with plotly.

Comment: Do you confirm that the `plotly.validators.table` module is present in the ouput of cx_Freeze in the lib/ folder?

Comment: As a matter of fact there's no such module. What's the way to add it via cx_Freeze?

Comment: Can you share package versions (`pip freeze`) and which package manager do you use?

Comment: @DavideTrono You need to explicitly add this module to cx_Freeze by modifying your compilation file in the build options. Concretely, you need to add `plotly.validators.table` in the `includes` (cf. https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html#build-exe)

Comment: @AlexandreD. I did it, but the error is the same: No Attribute CellsValidators

Comment: But did you see the module in your lib/ folder after cx_Freeze compilation?

Comment: Yes, it has been imported into the lib folder, what now?

Comment: @AlexandreD. if there's anything else you suggest to do, please enlight me.

Comment: Can you provide the full stacktrace in your post about the error you get with the cx_Freeze result ?

Comment: Actually after uninstalling plotly many times, after using many different version of such module, after I installed again the last version, the issue simply didn't happen anymore. I have no idea how this is happening, I wouldn't say I resolved anything, rather it just happenedto disappear. Thank you for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Uninstall plotly module.
2. Install older version of plotly module.
3. Now try building .exe file

(*If not working again, try further more old versions of plotly*)

**I hope it works.**

Comment: Honestly I have yet to try it, I gave you the 50 points because they would have been wasted otherwise.